Google Script Parsing Non-Duplicate Emails Into Google Sheets
I have been working on a script to parse emails received to a specific email account to a Google Sheet for further processing. Once the data is parsed into the sheet, it is further processed by existing formulas in columns C through F. How can I modify this script to instead of creating new rows, just populate columns A & B with the date and message respectively?
Thank you,
This is my current code. I imagine I need to alter the array push line and replace it with an insert.cells command, but an unfamiliar with the syntax.
 function gather() {
  let messages = getGmail();
  if (messages.length > 0) {
    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    curSheet.getRange(curSheet.getLastRow(), 1, messages.length, messages[0].length).setValues(messages);
      messages.push([m.getDate(), parseEmail(m.getPlainBody())])
  }
}

function getGmail() {
  const query = "is:unread";
  let threads = GmailApp.search(query,0,10);

    let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Parsed");
  if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("Parsed")}

  let messages = [];
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const m = thread.getMessages()[0];
    messages.push([m.getDate(), m.getPlainBody()]);
    m.markRead();
  });
  return messages;
}

function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/,/g,'')
        .replace(/\n\s*.+: /g,',')
        .replace(/^,/,'')
        .replace(/\n/g,'')
        .replace(/^[\s]+|[\s]+$/g,'')
        .replace(/\r/g,'')
        .split(',');
    let result = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(index => parsed[index]);

    return result;
}



You want to get messages from GMail and populate the results in a Google Sheet. You have an existing script which is intended to parse the "PlainBody" element of the message. But you want to modify the script to just populate columns A & B with the date and message respectively - parsing of the "plainBody" will be done by formula.
Caveat: No sample data has been supplied.
There are just 2 lines to edit in function gather()
SUGGESTED CHANGES:
Existing line#5
curSheet.getRange(curSheet.getLastRow(), 1, messages.length, messages[0].length).setValues(messages);

In this line curSheet.getLastRow() identifies the first row of output, but it will overwrite data already in the last row. Instead, use curSheet.getLastRow()+1
Amended line#5
curSheet.getRange(curSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, messages.length, messages[0].length).setValues(messages);


Existing line#6
messages.push([m.getDate(), parseEmail(m.getPlainBody())])

Delete this line altogether. Not only does is call the parseEmail function (which is no longer required), it fails because m is undefined.

If the OP wanted to use parseEmail instead of formula, then one would:

delete lines 5 & 6
use a loop to cycle through message "plainBody" values, parsing the contents
within the loop, add the date and the parsed "plainBody" "data to a temporary array
when the loop is complete, use a revised version of line#5 to setValues in the spreadsheet.

